# How to extract sequences of same characters from string ideally without regex?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a sample string (actually it is much longer) that looks like this:

```
st='+++----++-++++-----'
```

I want to extract groups of '+' and '-' to produce the following result:

```
list_of_strings=['+++----', '++-', '++++-----']
```

This is what I tried and it apparantly doesnt work:

```
st='+++----++-++++-----'

group_st=''

for i, k in zip(st, st[1:]):
    if i==k:
        group_st+=i
```

Comment: If `i` is `-` and `k` is `+` then create a new string, otherwise append `i` to existing string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
st='+++----++-++++-----'

out, current = [], ''
for ch in st:
    if current == '' or current[-1] == ch or ch == '-' and current[-1] == '+':
        current +=  ch
    else:
        out.append(current)
        current = ch

if current:
    out.append(current)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['+++----', '++-', '++++-----']
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked just fine. Would never thought about such solution.